# Counterexample relating the discriminant and ring of integers.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I guess the following statement is wrong, but I can not give a counter-example.

Let $n$ be a natural number. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$, be a field of degree $n$, i.e $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$. Also assume that $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n\}$ be algebraic integers which form a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $K$. Assume that $disc(\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n\})=d_1d_2$, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are coprime, and also $d_1$ is coprime with $n!$, i.e if $p \leq n$, then $p\nmid d_1$. If for every prime $p \mid d_1$, we have $v_p(d_1)<n$ (equivalently $p^n\nmid d_1$), then $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq \dfrac{1}{d_2}(\mathbb{Z}\alpha_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}\alpha_2\oplus \cdots\oplus \mathbb{Z}\alpha_n)$.

Is this statement true for every natural number $n$? Is it true for $n=q$, where $q$ is a prime number?

I can not find a counter-example. I can prove that there is no such counterexample for pure fields of prime degree $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[q]{a})$, where $a$ is a $q^{\rm th}$-power free integer. By a long conclusion, it is possible to show that the discriminant of these fields is equal to $rad(a)^{q-1}q^s$, for some $s\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your $p_j$ aren't used anywhere. Did you look at the (valuation of the) discriminant of extensions of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ ?

Comment: @reuns, You are right, I didn't used them. First I prepared to ask this question for general $n$, but I didn't sure if the statement is true or not. No, I didn't,l. I have no idea, how could I relate the field of $p-adic$ numbers to this problem.